# Why orthogonal polynomial can be used for ordered factor encoding?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, regression-coefficients, polynomial, categorical-encoding

[R Library: Contrast Coding Systems for categorical variables](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm#ORTHOGONAL), says we can use orthogonal polynomial for ordered factor encoding which the levels are equally spaced.

I do not understand why (mathematically) and intuition behind it. Could anyone explain it to me?

Does polynomial encoding have any relationship with polynomial regression?

Comment: It's saying it can be used for *equally spaced* ordinal variables like income and education. So basically for discretised continuous variable,  so yes same as polynomial regression but with discretised data as factors